# Scanning in contents of a file

Tags: java, string, file, java.util.scanner

I have a `file` that has the following content:

```
5

Derrick Rose

1 15 19 26 33 46

Kobe Bryant

17 19 33 34 46 47

Pau Gasol

1 4 9 16 25 36

Kevin Durant

17 19 34 46 47 48

LeBron James

5 10 17 19 34 47
```

With the a blank line between each of the names and numbers. However when I scan the file using the the nextLine(); method I get the following:

```
NAME: 
NAME: 
NAME: Derrick Rose
NAME: 
NAME: 1 15 19 26 33 46
NAME: 
NAME: Kobe Bryant
NAME: 
NAME: 17 19 33 34 46 47
NAME:
```

Can someone tell me where in my code the problem is occurring and why it is scanning in blank lines.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    int lim = scan.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < (lim * 2); i++)
    {
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("NAME: " + name);
    }
```

Comment: It's scanning blank lines, because your input has blank lines. You mention an error, can you elaborate? What error are you getting?

Comment: `nextLine()` reads your file line by line, including empty lines. Try something like `if (name.equals("")) continue;` to not print it out.

Comment: @Trobbins sorry I just fixed it, it doesn't get an error. But I was under the impression that the scanner ignores the blank lines between each line

Comment: @Beginner it does not. The scanner reads the input as it is.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you want to ignore the empty lines, you could just check the length of the line you're about to write to the console. It's not possible to not scan empty lines, you need to at least skip them to dive further into your stream.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
int lim = scan.nextInt();
for(int i = 0; i < (lim * 2); i++) {
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    if (name.trim().length() > 0)
         System.out.println("NAME: " + name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a newline in your input, then that will consume one call to `scan.NextLine()`, since that function delimits on newlines. If you want it to ignore blank lines then you should explicitly check for them and then explicitly increment your counter if the lines are not blank.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
int lim = scan.nextInt();
for(int i = 0; i < (lim * 2); )
{
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    if (!name.trim().equals("")) i++;
    System.out.println("NAME: " + name);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to trim()! :) !name.trim().equals("").

Comment: @user244255, Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for blank lines and ignore them.  The code below should do this.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
int lim = scan.nextInt();
for(int i = 0; i < (lim * 2); i++)
{
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    if (!name.equals("")){
        System.out.println("NAME: " + name);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `.equals()` when comparing strings.

Answer (score 0):

The below class ExcludeEmptyLines.java worked

```
    package com.stackoverflow.java.scannertest;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    /**
     * Created by fixworld.net on 03-September-2015.
     */

    public class ExcludeEmptyLines {

        public static void main(final String[] args) 
        throws FileNotFoundException {

            String dataFileFullPath = "<replace with full path to input file>";

            File inputFile = new File(dataFileFullPath);

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);

            int numEntries = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.println("NumEntries = " + numEntries);

            for(int i = 0; i <= (numEntries * 4); i++)
            {
                String inputLine = scan.nextLine();
                if(!inputLine.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    System.out.println("inputLine = " + inputLine);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Output from running it is

```
    NumEntries = 5
    inputLine = Derrick Rose
    inputLine = 1 15 19 26 33 46
    inputLine = Kobe Bryant
    inputLine = 17 19 33 34 46 47
    inputLine = Pau Gasol
    inputLine = 1 4 9 16 25 36
    inputLine = Kevin Durant
    inputLine = 17 19 34 46 47 48
    inputLine = LeBron James
    inputLine = 5 10 17 19 34 47
```